# Hover event in css doesn't work after the second onclick() event which is done using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a hovering transition using CSS and an `onclick()` event using JavaScript.

Everything works fine until the first click happens. When the second click happens the hover event doesn't work and the border-radius style is not applied, but the click events still work.

Even after every second click happening I want the hover transition to work and also the border-radius style should be applied. In short after the second click I want everything to be as it was before even the first click happened. I would like to solve this either with JavaScript or CSS.

```js
timesclicked = 0;
document.getElementById("container").addEventListener("click", function() 
{
    
    var x = document.getElementById('container');
    timesclicked+=1;
    if(timesclicked%2!=0)
    {   
        //obj.style.opacity = '0.5';
        x.style.transform = 'rotateZ(-360deg) scale(1.4)';
        x.style.transition = 'all 1.5s ease-in-out';
        setTimeout(() => {
            x.innerHTML = '<div style="font-size:16px; font-family: monospace; font-weight:bold; text-align:center; "> My Hero Academia, abbreviated as HeroAca is a Japanese superhero manga series written and illustrated by Kōhei Horikoshi. It has been serialized in Weekly Shōnen Jump since July 2014, and, as of February 2019, 22 volumes have been collected in tankōbon format.</div>'},'1300');
            
    }
    else
    {   
        x.style = 'border-radius:50px';
        x.style.transform = 'rotateZ(-45deg) scale(1)';
        x.style.transition = 'all 1.5s ease-in-out';
        setTimeout(() => {
            x.innerHTML = '<img src="https://picsum.photos/300g">'},'500');
        
    }
});
```

```css
    img
    {
        width: 300px;
        height: 300px;
    }
    #mainImage,#hoverImage 
    {
        left: 0px;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0px;
        border-radius: 50px;
    }

    #hoverImage
    {
        background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
        opacity: 0;
        transition: opacity 0.4s 0.1s ;
        border-radius: 50px;

    }
    
    #hoverImage:hover 
    {
        border-radius: 50px;
        opacity: 1; 
    }

    #container
    {
        background: url("https://picsum.photos/300");
        background-size: cover;
        width: 300px;
        height: 300px;
        position: absolute;
        top:20%;
        left:40%;
        transform: rotateZ(-45deg);
        border-radius: 50px;
        
    }
    #container:before
    {
    content: "";
        display: block;
        position: fixed;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        z-index: -1;
        background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
        border-radius: 50px;
    }
    .hoverBack
    {
        background-color: grey;
    }
```

```html
<body>
<div id="container" >
      <img id="mainImage" src="https://picsum.photos/300">
      <abbr title="Boku no Hero Academia" ><img id="hoverImage" src="https://picsum.photos/300">
     </abbr>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Instead of replacing the innerHTML every time, why don't you try removing and appending DOM Node?

Comment: i don't get it exactly, can u please be more elaborate with some code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are applying a `border-radius: 50px` to `#container` and `#mainImage` but when you reverse the animation on your second click, you replace the content of `#container` with a new image that does not have the ID `#mainImage` and therefore won't have rounded corners. You also have a typo in the image URL which results in an error when the new image is loaded from picsum.photos.

Your fixed code should look like this:

```
x.innerHTML = '<img id="mainImage" src="https://picsum.photos/300">'},'500');
```

Here is a [Codepen](https://codepen.io/AlexWayhill/pen/BeXZpP) with the updated code.

**Update 1**

To get the same effects after transitioning back into the original position, you need to give the container the same markup as it had before you changed its contents:

```
x.innerHTML = '<img id="mainImage" src="https://picsum.photos/300">'+
  '<abbr title="Boku no Hero Academia" >'+
  '<img id="hoverImage" src="https://picsum.photos/300?2"></abbr>';
```

Comment: thanks that solves the border radius part. What about the css transition on hover. it doesn't come back after the second click. Can u please help me with that?

Comment: @tejavenkat to receive the same effects you need to make sure that you set the contents to what you had before the animation. You could also save the previous contents in a variable and reset it to the original (as shown in the updated Codepen).

Comment: @tejavenkat great to hear, your welcome! Real nice animation I must say, that makes me curious how your complete web page might look like :-)

Comment: i have completed it if you want to see my page send me ur mail or something like that so that i can share with u

Comment: hey, you can check it, i have sent u a mail. Now u can delete the comment

Comment: @tejavenkat very nice and well done! Just a quick hint: you can simply remove the "C:/Users/dell/Desktop/" from the HTML page and use relative links instead. You can then simply move the pages into whatever directory you choose, just make sure the images remain in the "blog content" folder. Keep up the good work and thanks for sharing!